# Embedded images in email with sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, sendgrid

Trying to use an embedded image in my template but the email won't be sent. The path should be correct and I am getting no error. When I delete the image everything works fine and I am receiving the mail.

```
const mailController = {
sendAnswers: async(certificate) => {
    try {
        let pathToAttachment = `./documents/${certificate.company.name}/${certificate.company.name}_${certificate.company.selectedLanguage}.pdf`;
        let attachment = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString("base64");

        let answerTemplate = {
            to: 'invoice@test.de',
            from: 'no-reply@test.de', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
            subject: 'Test',
            text: 'Test Test Test',
            html: `
                <img alt="test" src="cid:logo">
                <div style="margin: 20px 20%; padding: 24px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius: 6px;"><h1 style="text-align: center">Thank You! ${certificate.company.name}</h1>
                <p style="text-align: center">Text<br>
                More Text
                More and More Text</p>
                </div>
            `,
            attachments: [
                {
                    content: attachment,
                    filename: `${certificate.company.name}_Answers.pdf`,
                    type: "application/pdf",
                    disposition: "attachment"
                },
                {
                    content: fs.readFileSync(`./assets/images/Changemaker-Siegel.png`, { encoding: 'base64'}),
                    filename: "Changemaker",
                    type: "image/png",
                    content_id: "logo",
                    disposition: "inline"
                }
            ]
        };

        await sgMail.send(answerTemplate);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    
        if (error.response) {
          console.error(error.response.body)
        }
      }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your logo attachment is not being sent as a base 64 string. You are reading the attachment as if its encoding is base 64, which is a different thing.

So, you have:

```js
            content: fs.readFileSync(`./assets/images/Changemaker-Siegel.png`, {
              encoding: "base64",
            }),
```

But you need:

```js
            content: fs.readFileSync(`./assets/images/Changemaker-Siegel.png`).toString("base64"),
```

Comment: Sadly that does not seem to work either. I am still not receiving any mail. Should I maybe just use the dynamic templates ?

Comment: I just tried this code and it worked for me, inlining the image into the email successfully. Maybe you can edit your question and share your latest code? Or using dynamic templates is even more powerful and means you have to do less in your code to build what the email looks like.

Comment: I am using the dynamic templates now and they are working great! Thank you for your help

Comment: Good news! If my answer helped at all, please mark it as accepted, so others can see too. Thanks!